# Grouping birthday results by Month

Tags: mysql, date, group-by

I have a list of users and their birthdays. I need to print the list of birthdays for each month and grouped by day. For example:

Monday 24th (2): Herpina Derpina, John Doe

Tuesday 27th (1): Nicolas Cage

Friday 28th (1): Michael Jackson

How could I achieve that with one single SQL call? If I group them this way, I will lose records:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user GROUP BY MONTH(birthday)
```

Any ideas? (I'm using mysql + php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the count which is an aggregate function and the detailed records in the same query.  If the names are essential then you will have to manually construct the counts in PHP and then display the records under the required format.

Comment: you're right. i implemented a solution on the php side. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MONTH(birthday) month,
       FORMAT(birthday, '%W %D') day,
       COUNT(user) count,
       GROUP_CONCAT(user SEPARATOR ',') users
FROM table
GROUP BY MONTH(birthday), FORMAT(birthday, '%W %D')
```

Comment: but that doesn't bring all the names :s